# How to hide the private key for sign trnx with NodeJS?

Tags: web3js, wallets, nodejs, private-key

When I sign a transacction in a website I do it with Metamask and my private key is safe.

Now I am signing transactions automatically from a NodeJS like the next code.

**Can I somehow hide my privateKey in case someone has access to the server?**

```
const privateKey = 'my wallet secret private key';  

const rawTransaction = { "to": 0x000000, "value": value, "gas": 100000 };
    
web3js.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, privateKey)
    .then(signedTx => web3js.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction))    
    .then(function(receipt){ console.log("Tranx Done!"); 
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is difficult to achieve because even if you encrypt the key and save it in a database, a hacker will be able to access the database and decrypt your key. But you can make it more difficult.

**1.** You can encrypt your private key with the "crypto-js" package, and save it in an external text file (in a parent folder of your project) and recover it in your NODE script after.

Then you can read that file and decrypt the key to sign your transaction.

It's not perfect but at least it helps make it not so obvious.

Maybe this code helps you to encrypt and decrypt it. Good luck.

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

// Encrypt and save into a external file
var cipherKey = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my private key', 'secret password').toString();


// Decrypt in your code
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherKey , 'secret password');
var privateKey= bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(privateKey); //'mi private key'
```

**2.** You can declare your private key in an external environment variable to prevent that your key is hard-coded in your code and accidentally sent to GitHub or somewhere else ;) You can save your key in a .env file in your project directory and read this file with the [npm package dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/full/custom/path/to/your/env/vars' })
var yourKey= process.env.MYKEY;
```

**.env** file

```
MYKEY=123abc
```

**3.** Both 1 and 2 together ;)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I am saving my private key value in an external .js file in the parent folder of my server project.

```
const private  = require('../private.js');
var privateKey = private.PRIVATE_KEY;
```

The code of private.js file to declare the var value

```
module.exports.PRIVATE_KEY= "00000000000000000";
```

Comment: Cool solution to avoid load third party modules like "dotenv"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, best way to do this is use **crypto-js**, however, if you want to get even step further, and don't have any physical copy of your secret password, just start the script with arguments containing your secret password, just make sure you clear your cmd logs. You can also use input prompts.